# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_process_projection_requirements' While using Matplotlib and Tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, error-handling

I'm new to Python and I am currently trying to create a Matplotlib Bar Chart embedded within a Tkinter GUI, with a navigation tool bar. This is the code I have written.

```
from tkinter import *

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import 
(FigureCanvasTkAgg,NavigationToolbar2Tk)

from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler

from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import pandas as pd

root = Tk ()

# root.wn_title ('SAMPLE')

total_cases = pd.read_csv('c:\\Users\\vish\\Downloads\\total_cases.csv')

p1= plt.plot(total_cases , kind = 'bar')

fig = Figure( figsize = (5,4) , dpi = 100 )

ax = Figure.add_subplot (111).plot(p1)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg ( fig , root )

canvas.draw()

canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side = TOP, fill = BOTH, expand = 1)

total_cases.plot(kind = 'bar')

ax.set_title('Total Corona Cases')

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, root)

toolbar.update()

canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side = TOP, fill = BOTH, expand = 1)

def on_key(event):
    print('You Pressed {}'.format(event.key))
    key_press_handler(event, canvas, toolbar)
    
canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event' , on_key)    

def Quit():
    root.quit()
    root.destroy()
    return

button = Button(root, text = 'QUIT' , command = Quit )

button.pack (BOTTOM)

root.mainloop()
```

On running, I recieve the following Error Message " AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_process_projection_requirements "

```
runfile('C:/Users/vish/Desktop/tkinter graph.py', wdir='C:/Users/vish/Desktop')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\vish\Desktop\tkinter graph.py", line 28, in <module>
    ax = Figure.add_subplot(111).plot(p1)

  File "C:\Users\vish\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1396, in add_subplot
    self._process_projection_requirements(*args, **kwargs)

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_process_projection_requirements'
```

Above is the full error message.

I use Spyder as my IDE.

Hoping I can find some tips on how to fix this and improve my code.

Thank you.

Comment: can you post full error code

Comment: @CoolCloud I have updated the question. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: i think the value of `ax` is int and thats the prob? im not sure

Comment: Should `Figure.add_subplot(111).plot(p1)` be `fig.add_subplot(111).plot(p1)`?

Comment: @CoolCloud This seems to be the case. I'll see if I can change up the code a little bit.

Comment: @acw1668 add_subplot() is within the class Figure I believe, that's why I've used `Figure.add_subplot(111).plot(p1) ` , nevertheless I will try out your suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: You should use the instance name `fig` instead of the class name `Figure` when calling the `add_subplot()` function.

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks for the input ! It works now. Much appreciated.